# Container view action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I'm using a container view (as suggested in this tutorial: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/) to share a view between 2 view controllers in a storyboard.

In my container view I have a `UIButton` that I want to trigger a specific action in my first view controller and another action in my second view controller. How is this possible? Also can I wire up outlets in my view controller to my container view? I have not come up with a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container view is "owned" by some ContainerViewController, I assume? Can't it tell to its child view controllers what they should do, when the button on container is pushed, since it is owned by the same VC?

When button is pushed it calls some method that tells "child" view controllers what to do... for example:

```
// On ContainerVC.m
- (void)buttonPushed:(id)sender {
    [self.firstVC doYourThing];
    [self.secondVC doYourStuff];
}
```

Hope I get the right idea of yours